# qt4 build fails with message error

Tags: build, qt4

I'm trying to build the qt-all-opensource-src-4.5.3 sources, I'm on a debian testing and build fails with the following error message:

```
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/preprocessorcontrol.o preprocessorcontrol.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/replacetoken.o replacetoken.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/tokenreplacements.o tokenreplacements.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/textreplacement.o textreplacement.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/portingrules.o portingrules.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/qtsimplexml.o qtsimplexml.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/projectporter.o projectporter.cpp
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/proparser.o proparser.cpp
    In file included from translationunit.h:48:0,
                     from projectporter.cpp:47:
    codemodel.h: In instantiation of ‘void CodeModel::Collection::add(CollectedType*) [with CollectedType = CodeModel::Type]’:
    codemodel.h:296:36:   required from here
    codemodel.h:99:7: error: ‘insert’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
    codemodel.h:99:7: note: declarations in dependent base ‘QMultiHash’ are not found by unqualified lookup
    codemodel.h:99:7: note: use ‘this->insert’ instead
    g++ -c -pipe -g -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtXml -I../../../include -I.moc/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/fileporter.o fileporter.cpp
    make[5]: *** [.obj/release-shared/projectporter.o] Error 1
    make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/habeeb/lab/xml/debian/3rd/qt/4.5.3/qt-all-opensource-src-4.5.3/tools/porting/src'
    make[4]: *** [sub-src-make_default] Error 2
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/habeeb/lab/xml/debian/3rd/qt/4.5.3/qt-all-opensource-src-4.5.3/tools/porting'
    make[3]: *** [sub-porting-make_default-ordered] Error 2
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/habeeb/lab/xml/debian/3rd/qt/4.5.3/qt-all-opensource-src-4.5.3/tools'
    make[2]: *** [sub-tools-make_default-ordered] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/habeeb/lab/xml/debian/3rd/qt/4.5.3/qt-all-opensource-src-4.5.3'
```

Code in question, model.h (lines 95 to 100):

```
    class Collection: public QMultiHash
    {
    public:
         void add(CollectedType *collectedItem)
        { insert(collectedItem->name(), collectedItem); }
    };
```

IS tis related to missing library ? how can I fix this ?

THank you !

Comment: Can you provide the code at codemodel.h:99?

Comment: If you read that msg closely, it says "note: use ‘this->insert’ instead"

..but that warning makes me feel like theres a bigger issue

Comment: public:
     void add(CollectedType *collectedItem)
    { insert(collectedItem->name(), collectedItem); }
};

Comment: any toughts ? thanks!

Comment: Please post a substantial code sample if you'd like some more help here. Something well formatted will make it easier for others to help.

Comment: have you tried adding a "#include <QMultiHash>"? Are the QT libraries on your path?

Comment: @Zatla00 Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639053/name-lookups-in-c-templates

Comment: @yankee2905 i've not done any change on the package that I downloaded, i only run ./configure and then make command.