# stragety of the name lookup about full specialization of function?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is two-phase name lookup for template from iso-standard:

> - When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template definition, the usual lookup rules (6.4.1, 6.4.2) are used for non-dependent names.
> - The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known

Sample codes:

```
#include <iostream>

void WithoutTemplate(int) {std::cout << "NonTemplate: int\n";}

template<typename T>
void WithTemplate(T) {std::cout << "no match\n";}

template<>
void WithTemplate(int) {std::cout <<"Template: int\n";}

template<typename T>
void test(T)
{
    WithTemplate(1.1);
    WithoutTemplate(1.1);
}

void WithoutTemplate(double) {std::cout << "nontemplate: double\n";}

template<>
void WithTemplate(double) {std::cout << "template: double\n";}

int main()
{
    test(1.1);
}
```

output:

> template: double
>   NonTemplate: int

There are two functions: `WithTemplate` and `WithoutTemplate`. The parameter `1.1` is non-dependent(though it is prvalue, which has no name? I assume it still obey non-dependent name's rules)

- name lookup of `WithoutTemplate` meets 2-phase lookup, because when calling `WithoutTemplate(1.1)`, `void WithoutTemplate(double)` is not visible. So the output `NonTemplate: int` is easy to understand.
- However, the case which invokes full specialization function quite confuses me. its behaviour is opposite to the standard's rules(2-phase lookup). I thought it should output `template: int`

So, is there other name lookup rules for specialization? Or something else I misunderstand?

Here is what I have read:

- [Difference between instantiation and specialization in c++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates)
- [Name lookups in C++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639053/name-lookups-in-c-templates)

Comment: Two-phase name lookup isn't relevant here; your template definition doesn't use any dependent names - the only name you use is `std::cout` which is fully qualified. (1.1 isn't a name.)

Comment: @AlanStokes I think `WithoutTemplate` uses 2-phase name lookup here which also uses non-dependent name. So `WithTemplate ` may also use it, but I'm not sure, so the question is `stragety...`

Comment: The names looked up within `test` are non-dependent, so the normal rules apply. At the point where you call `WithoutTemplate` only one definition is visible, so that's the one that is called. (If you were to replace `1.1` with `(T) 1.1` you might see different results.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour, because you define the explicit specialization of `WithTemplate<double>` after it has been implicitly instantiated through the call `WithTemplate(1.1)`. Explicit specializations must appear before any use of them that would cause instantiation - see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization.

So there's no point trying to reconcile the behaviour with what the standard says; the standard explicitly says nothing about what should happen here.